# Semi Automated Classification plugin (QGIS) error when trying to create ROI

Tags: qgis, python, remote-sensing

When I try to create a new ROI through Semi-Automated Classification plugin (SCP) for QGIS, I keep getting a message saying:

"It appears that SciPy is not correctly installed. Please, see this page for information about SciPy installation  http://semiautomaticclassificationmanual-v3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation_ubuntu.html#qgis-download-and-installation"

(the page on this link didn't help me, unfortunately)

Any idea on how to solve this?

Versions:

QGIS 2.8.2

SCP 4.3.3

Mac OS X 10.7.5

Comment: Did you allready install SciPy? [KyngChaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/python) maintains binaries for Python modules as well as the go-to OsX source for QGIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved it. Uninstalled and intalled SciPy module (http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/python) again and it worked.

Comment: In that case you should mark this as the answer to your question (the green tick on the left).